# How to Sum an income from TOP 20% of Customers?

Tags: powerbi, dax, top-n

Language: DAX

Program: Power BI.

The problem is simple (not for me though) - i need to know how much of my company's profits come from 20% of its TOP customers. I have a "Customers" list, and "Profit" list. Currently, this list consists of 2035 Customers, every each has a number of profit we gained through every single trade. Keep in mind that with most of them we made more than 1 trade, so actaully I have a list of ca. 20000 deals we made with 2035 customers, and I have a make a formula which summarises the profit we have from TOP 20% of them.

I found a syntax on Microsoft Page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492198.aspx

although i have little idea how it works...

Thanks everyone for trying in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to spend a little time working through the specific model, but the concepts are the same as this pattern: http://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/

You would calculate a table that includes your customers, the sum of their sales, and rank the customers by their sales.

Then you'd wrap that in a filter on the rank >=20.
Then you'd sum over the resulting set.